# How to Load a class with @ConditionalOnProperty set as false.?

Tags: spring-boot

I have class which has Condition on property same as given below.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value="abc.present", havingValue="true")
```

In my `Application.properties` file abs.present is set as false,
is there any way through which without changing the value of abs.present i can load this class?.

Comment: you can do with command line arguement during application start up

Comment: You can set it when during the application starting up with writing -abc.present=true or you can write own your condition class to select from database or something. Cant change when running your application.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Spring you could always just create a new instance of the class using `new`.